# How to reset price slider input value, on click, using global state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

[Live codesandbox link.](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/jd-sephy/SETS/main?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Fshared%2Fheader%2FHeader.tsx%3A20%2C22&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkv9garo000h356or4wfvgz5%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkv9garo000c356o22r0it8x%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkv9garo000g356or0vbw6xm%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkv9garo000e356o5z2zzv36%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clkv9garo000c356o22r0it8x%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkv9garo000c356o22r0it8x%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkv9garo000b356oq401dne1%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522view%2522%253A%2522code%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252Fshared%252FTable.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkv9jfrk00jf356ngohierz5%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpackage.json%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkvaxeyp0122356octao5557%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252Fshared%252Fheader%252FHeader.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkvb5tfc00fr356nmdvdbyyt%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clkvb5tfc00fr356nmdvdbyyt%2522%257D%252C%2522clkv9garo000e356o5z2zzv36%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkv9garo000e356o5z2zzv36%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkv9gxxk010w356ozsm178g8%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkvb2aj4000c356n6htrmqw7%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clkv9gxxk010w356ozsm178g8%2522%257D%252C%2522clkv9garo000g356or0vbw6xm%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkv9garo000g356or0vbw6xm%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clkv9gvu400p0356oovuudr7l%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkv9garo000f356obushqn0g%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clkv9gb12001qhlij9veh1413%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkv9gvu400p0356oovuudr7l%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

When a user drags the price range slider, the data in the table filters properly. However, when a user clicks the Clear button, the table does reset properly, **but the input field does not reset**. It stays exactly where the user left it. Illustrated below, I dragged the input to 65,000. And upon hitting the clear, it doesn't reset, but the table data does.

You can try this live at the [live link](https://kpvtz2-5173.csb.app/).

I believe the problem is that in my PriceRange.tsx component below, I'm using local state for the Input. Whereas for the Slider, I'm using the Zustand global state. I need to use the global state for the Input, but I'm not sure how.

[image: value not resetting]

**PriceRange.tsx:**

```
export const PriceRange = ({ onChange, min, max }: PriceRangeProps) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<number | number[]>(min);

  // As user drags slider, API value changes
  const handleValueChange = (newValue: number | number[]) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    onChange(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Flex direction="column">
        <Input
          value={value.toLocaleString()}
          onChange={(e) => handleValueChange(parseFloat(e.target.value))}
        />
        <Slider
          range
          value={value}
          onChange={handleValueChange}
          min={min}
          max={max}
        />
      </Flex>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Zustand store (global state) - store.tsx:**

```
const useFilterStore = create<FilterState>((set) => ({
  ...
  priceRangeFilter: null,
  ...
  setPriceRange: (value: number) =>
    set((state) => ({ ...state, priceRangeFilter: value })),
  ...
}));
```

**handleFilters.tsx:**

```
import useFilterStore from "../store";

...

export const handlePriceRangeFilter = (value: number | number[]) => {
  useFilterStore.setState({ priceRangeFilter: value });
};
```

**Header.tsx:**

```
export const Header = ({ data, isLoading, error }: HeaderProps) => {
  ...

  // Bring in global state
  const {
    ...
    priceRangeFilter,
  } = useFilterStore();

  const minPrice = Math.min(
    ...data.map((i) =>
      Math.min(
        ...i.equipments.map((item) => parseFloat(item["sale-price"].text))
      )
    )
  );

  const maxPrice = Math.max(
    ...data.map((i) =>
      Math.max(
        ...i.equipments.map((item) => parseFloat(item["sale-price"].text))
      )
    )
  );

  // On click of clear button, update the zustand store states for all filters
  const handleClearFilter = () => {
    useFilterStore.setState({
      searchFilter: "",
      manufacturerDropdownFilter: "",
      provinceDropdownFilter: "",
      cityDropdownFilter: "",
      currentPage: 0,
      priceRangeFilter: minPrice,
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section className="header">
        ...
        <PriceRange
          value={priceRangeFilter}
          onChange={handlePriceRangeFilter}
          min={minPrice}
          max={maxPrice}
        />
        <ClearButton onClick={handleClearFilter} />
      </section>
    </>
  );
};
```

**ClearFiltersButton.tsx:**

```
export const ClearButton = ({ onClick }: ClearButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={onClick}>Clear</Button>
    </>
  );
};
```